# Is there a way to pass different repositories into a generic method and have them use variables generated within the method?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-core, refactoring

In my current class I have the following blocks of code

```
int.TryParse(formDataDictionary["CountryId"], out var countryId);
var country = countryId > 0 ? _countriesRepository.GetCountryById(countryId) : null;
var searchedCountryName = country != null ? country.Name : string.Empty;

int.TryParse(formDataDictionary["SubjectId"], out var subjectId);
var subject = subjectId > 0 ? _subjectsRepository.GetFullSubjectDetailsById(subjectId) : null;
var searchedSubjectName = subject != null ? subject.Name : string.Empty;
```

As you can see they are almost identical except for their use of different repositories.

I would like to stick them in a generic method that simply returns a name string, but I don't know how I can pass in a repo and have it use a particular method to get the subject or country.

Is this possible or is it more trouble than it's worth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible when you pass the part where you access the repository with a delegate. Moreover, in order to access the `Name` property, your `country` and your `subject` variables should have a common base type (I just assumed as an example an interface `IHasName` with just one property `string Name {get;}`).

```
public string GetSearchedName<T>(string dictionaryKey, Func<int,T> getValue) where T : IHasName, class
{
    int.TryParse(formDataDictionary[dictionaryKey], out var id);
    T item = id > 0 ? getValue.Invoke(id) : null;
    return item?.Name ?? string.Empty;
}
```

Note that I used the `class` constraint in order that `item` can be `null`. I also simplified the last line by using the null coalescing operator (your question has the refactoring tag).

Usage is

```
string seachedCountryName = GetSearchedName("CountryId", (id) => _countriesRepository.GetCountryById(id));
string searchedSubjectName = GetSearchedName("SubjectId", (id) => _subjectsRepository.GetFullSubjectDetailsById(id));
```

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was hoping for. An example and an explanation of usage, plus the little refactoring on top. Thank you.